# Qtip2 mouse positioning bug with jquery > 1.9 when use negative margin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tooltip, qtip2

I use qTip2 for tooltip in my web application and since jquery 1.9, the tooltip are no longer placed in the same place.

With jquery < 1.9 :

[image]

With jquery >= 1.9 :

[image]

I have see that **jQuery in both version does take negative margins into account; It seems jQuery 1.8.3 was counting body offset incorrectly, in jQuery 1.9.x it's fixed**

I have notice that the bug appears when we use negative margin and when the number of rows of my table doesn't exceed viewport height. I use negative margin to set footer on the bottom of the page.

You can see a simplified jsfiddle example :

Tooltip isn't good placed (number of rows doesn't exceed viewport height) : http://jsfiddle.net/fDavN/12545/

Tooltip is good placed (number of rows exceed viewport height) : 
http://jsfiddle.net/fDavN/12546/

With jQuery version < 1.9, its works with the two case :

http://jsfiddle.net/Francks11/fDavN/12558/

http://jsfiddle.net/Francks11/fDavN/12559/

Can you help me please?

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to set the `target: 'mouse'` ? In other words, can the target been replaced by something else?

Comment: Good idea. Thanks :-)